# How to manually increment UNIX_TIMESTAMP() when insert a new row with liquibase?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a `cart` table with a `cart_number` column which I would like to be the current time in milliseconds.

I've created a database change log file and everything works fine but the problem is that the span of time between 2 inserts is too short to get a "unique" `cart_number`. Here is the liquibase insert:

```
<property name="now" value="UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" dbms="mysql"/>

<changeSet id="2" author="Me">
    <insert tableName="cart">
        <column name="user_id" value="1"/>
        <column name="cart_number" valueDate="${now}"/>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="cart">
        <column name="user_id" value="2"/>
        <column name="cart_number" valueDate="${now}"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

And I know this isn't a solution, but I've tried to write something like `${now+1}` but it didn't worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A (pure) timestamp is rarely (just don't want to say "never") a good candidate for an identifying column.

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea to register the cart_number as a timestamp because it won't be updatable and I want to simulate some *fancy* identifying number for the cart. The "user_id" is in fact the cart PK because there is a 1:1 mapping between these two entities and this PK is generated using auto_increment.